# Finding a coefficient of the variable in a function

Tags: functions, polynomials

$f(x) = x^5 + ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$

$f(1) = 2$

$f(2) = 3$

$f(3) = 4$

$f(4) = 5$

$f(5) = 6$

$b = \underline{\qquad}$

How should I answer this kind of question?

Edit: Actually I had already found the answer that b is an element of Real Numbers through some elimination. But I'm still not sure is it true or false. It took quite a long time and maybe there is something that i was forgetting to answer this question Much Faster.

Comment: Have you taken linear algebra?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the equation
$$f(x)-x-1=0$$
has roots at $x=1,2,3,4,5$. Then $f(x)-x-1$ can be factored as
$$f(x)-x-1=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)$$
and so
$$f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)+x+1.$$
Then take a boring calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 conditions and 5 variables. For example, $f(1)=2$ means $f(1)=1+a+b+c+d+e=2\to a+b+c+d+e=1$. Idem with others 4 conditions and resolve this equation system

Answer (score 0):

You can view it as a linear system of five equations in the five variables $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$. Then use [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your system of equations provide you 5 equations for 5 variables. You just need to plug them together
\begin{align}
&&a+b+d+e+2 &=2\\
&&16 a+8 b+8 d+e+40&=3\\
&&81 a+27 b+27 d+e+270&=4\\
&&256 a+64 b+64 d+e+1088&=5\\
&&625 a+125 b+125 d+e+3250&=6
\end{align}

and solve using the method that you fell the most comfortable with. To help you I leave here the answer you should get after solving your system.

$$(a,b,c,d,e)=(-15,85,-225,275,-119)$$